# How do I show the description box of the properties window in Visual Studio 2010 if it is hidden?

Tags: visual-studio

How do I show the description box of the properties window in Visual Studio 2010 if it is hidden?

[image: Missing properites box]

For example, the following image shows the description box. It reads "Load: Occurs whenever the user loads the form."

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it happens (VS2015) and nothing can bring it back unless I close and re-open VS

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this ? visuals studio 2015 still has this very same bug.

Comment: I just fixed my Visual Studio 2015 using [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6171471/224976). I had to undock, redock, and then I could grab the vertical resize cursor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was caused by the description box lenght having been dragged to zero. To solve the problem I had to un-dock the properties box and resize it as long as possible. It is then just possible to find the verticle resize cursor at the bottom and resize the box.

Comment: I just had this same problem, no idea why the description height went to zero. Un-dock like @Alex said, and then Maximize the Properties window. With that the splitter to the description may not be visible but it will be easy to grab and drag. HTH

Comment: I tried this with a WPF application and it didn't work at all :(

Comment: Tried this but doesn't work for me even when maximized.

Comment: When undocked, the vertical resize cursor who show for a split second and then disappear. Once I re-docked, then I could click and drag the vertical resize cursor

Answer (score 4):

Right click and select "Description" menu item.

Comment: I think you're right but I must have had some other conflict because my descriptions menu item was already checked! I fixed it by restoring my settings back to the default settings. [MSDN: How to: Reset Your Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If the suggestion by Alex doesn't work, an alternative is to click `WINDOW` > `Reset Window Layout`.

**Warning:** This will reset every window so best used only as a last resort.

Comment: This didn't help for me. Still no descriptions. I also tried to uncheck and check the "Descriptions" checkbox in the popup menu in the properties window.

Answer (score 2):

Another potential solution that worked for me.

1. Righ-click on the Properties Window and uncheck the Description in the popup menu. If it's not checked, then go to the next step.
2. Exit VS and launch again.
3. Load your project/solution then select an object on your design surface, right-click and select properties.
4. In the Properties window, right-click, and in the popup menu, check the Description item. The Descrip[tion area should open up and display a description.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, that is why I ended up reading this.  I tried the right click and unchecked the option for description, and rechecked it. didn't help. I then moved my mouse over the very bottom of the little window pane and saw a cursor that looked  2 arrows over a horizontal line [here is a picture of arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0BGv.jpg). By dragging that line up, I was able to get my descriptions back.

Answer (score 0):

A bit extreme, but after trying everything, this is what worked for me:

1. [Download Window Detective](http://windowdetective.sourceforge.net/)
2. Undock and Maximize the Properties Window
3. Pick the **Properties Window** with **Window Detective**, and look for the **Description Pane** in the hierarchy
4. Flash the **Description Pane** to find out where it is
5. Set its **WS_CAPTION** and **WS_THICKFRAME** styles on
6. Resize the **Description Pane** to give it some height :)
7. Set its **WS_CAPTION** and **WS_THICKFRAME** styles off
8. Redock the **Property Window**.

Everybody happy

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem in an ASP.NET project and solved by rendering the .aspx page clicking the *Design* bottom left button, then when I returned to the *Source* view the descriptions now appeared.