# Property description panel missing from WPF project property window in Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

For some reason I do not see the property description panel in my WPF project in Visual Studios.

Here is a screenshot take from the internet with the panel
[image]

Here is what is showing up on my machine

[image]

As you can see the description for my properties do not show up. This was a very useful feature when I was working with Windows Forms and I would love if it worked with WPF.

I'm using Visual Studios 2010 professional edition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I show the description box of the properties window in Visual Studio 2010 if it is hidden?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381555/how-do-i-show-the-description-box-of-the-properties-window-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 0):

Just mouse over the property and it'll tool-tip the description.

Or see [How do I show the description box of the properties window in Visual Studio 2010 if it is hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381555/how-do-i-show-the-description-box-of-the-properties-window-in-visual-studio-2010) (now this is for Win Forms, not WPF - but could be the same solution for you)

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I just get the property name and its current value.

Comment: @the86guy have added a link

Comment: I actually tried that before posting my question, didn't work at all for me :(